# SmartTarget 2010 - Deployment web service WSDL 404

Tags: tridion, smarttarget

I've installed Fredhopper on a different server than where Tridion sits and have followed the instructions for setting up the SmartTarget deployment web service for Fredhopper using the instructions here (login required):

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2010_SP1/task_7DA6ABC3212F47FEACF03CD73411CB02

I should be able to go to my newly deployed web service and view the WSDL, however when attempting to do so I get a 404 message. If I go to http://[machinename]:8180/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService I can get a page showing the methods available, but clicking the WSDL link doesn't work.

The reason this is an issue is because deploying content to Fredhopper from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 doesn't work as it cannot read the WSDL of the service:

> Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, unable to persist the fredhopper XML through the webservice, Failed to access the WSDL at: http://[machinename]:8180/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService?wsdl. It failed with:  http://[machinename]:8180/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService?wsdl

Found someone came across the same issue in Tridion forums as well but no solution was found:

https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7415

Has anyone ever come across this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of questions...

- You mention SmartTarget 2010 but also Tridion 2011 SP1. SmartTarget 2010 was built for SDL Tridion 2009, any reason why you're not using a more recent version of ST? (latest version is ST 2011 SP2).
- Are you running the deployment webservice inside Fredhopper's JBoss? As far as I know this is not supported as the JBoss version shipped with Fredhopper is highly customized.

With that said, I have used the deployment webservice on Tomcat without any issues.

N

Comment: Ah I see, I was attempting to run it under Fredhoppers JBOSS instance. I've since installed Tomcat 7 and running it on port 8080 but still can't access the WSDL at http://[machinename]:8080/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService?wsdl so starting to think it might be something else.

Comment: We also ship 2 different WebServices (J2EE and non-J2EE), which is basically whether it should use EJBs or not. Use the non-J2EE with Tomcat.

Comment: That was it, used the wrong version of the WAR file. Thanks for your help!